# ceph health warm message on 19.04

Tags: ceph

I command ceph-deploy mgr create node1
cluster:
    id:     cb144140-f41a-464a-a834-d7817785e149
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            3 modules have failed dependencies

services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum monitor
    mgr: monitor(active)
    osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in

data:
    pools:   0 pools, 0 pgs
    objects: 0  objects, 0 B
    usage:   0 B used, 0 B / 0 B avail
    pgs:

Answer (score 0):

The '3 modules have failed dependencies" indicates the ceph-mgr dashboard is not working.

One can still work with the ceph-mon(s) and ceph-osd(s), just not the ceph-mgr(s).

This is a know problem with ceph mimic 13.2.4+dfsg1-0ubuntu2.1  packaged with Ubuntu disco 19.04.

See:

https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/25585
http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/38788
http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/37472

As stated in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ceph/+bug/1832105  "The ceph primary development platform is Debian, on which the workaround has been available for some time." Unfortunately this has not been the case for Ubuntu disco.